# System.InvalidOperationException when creating Word file with Gembox

Tags: gembox-document

We are merging a Word template document that contains merge fields using Gembox Document.  We noticed when some of the field values contain special characters \t or \n, an exception occurs...

> An error occured - Text cannot contain new line (' '), carriage return
> (' ') or tab (' ') characters. If you want to break the text or insert
> a tab, insert SpecialCharacter instance with specific
> SpecialCharacterType to the parent's InlineCollection.

We found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345256/creating-word-file-with-gembox) which describes a solution to the issue, but we are not seeing how to apply that to our scenario.

This is our code which throws the exception...

```
    public static void Merge(DocumentModel word, PricingSummaryModel model)
    {
        word.MailMerge.FieldMerging += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.FieldName.Contains("CustomField."))
            {
                var trove = FindCustomFieldValueTrove(e.FieldName, model);
                var value = ProcessCustomField(e.FieldName, e.Field.GetInstructionText(), trove);

                e.Inline = new Run(e.Document, value) { CharacterFormat = e.Field.CharacterFormat.Clone() };
                e.Cancel = false;
            }
        };

        word.MailMerge.Execute(model);
    }
```

We can fix the problem by removing any special characters first...

[image]

But then we lose the special characters of course.  For our scenario, how can this be done?  We aren't "constructing" a document as referenced in the aforementioned [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345256/creating-word-file-with-gembox).  Rather we are starting with a Word template and essentially mail merging field values for the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to handle those special characters and add the appropriate element(s) to the `e.Inlines` collection.

For example, try this:

```cs
var value = ProcessCustomField(e.FieldName, e.Field.GetInstructionText(), trove);

int startIndex = 0, currentIndex = 0, length = value.Length;
for (; currentIndex < length; currentIndex++)
{
    char c = value[currentIndex];
    if (c == '\t' || c == '\n')
    {
        e.Inlines.Add(
            new Run(e.Document, value.Substring(startIndex, currentIndex - startIndex))
            { CharacterFormat = e.Field.CharacterFormat.Clone() });

        e.Inlines.Add(
            new SpecialCharacter(e.Document, c == '\t' ? SpecialCharacterType.Tab : SpecialCharacterType.LineBreak)
            { CharacterFormat = e.Field.CharacterFormat.Clone() });

        startIndex = currentIndex + 1;
    }
    else if (currentIndex == length - 1)
        e.Inlines.Add(
            new Run(e.Document, value.Substring(startIndex, currentIndex - startIndex + 1))
            { CharacterFormat = e.Field.CharacterFormat.Clone() });
}

e.Cancel = false;
```